# TypeError: preg_match(): Argument #2 ($subject) must be of type string, array given on linux server

Tags: linux, laravel-7, jenssegers-mongodb

Having this issue on the linux server when accessing data from mongodb using jenssengers package. It does not show up on the local server during development. Below is the complete error i receive

```
/home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(930): preg_match('/^(\\d{4})-(\\d{1...', Array)
#1 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(906): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->isStandardDateFormat(Array)
#2 /home/abc/abc/vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/Eloquent/Model.php(111): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->asDateTime(Array)
#3 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(165): Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model->asDateTime(Array)
#4 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(127): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->addDateAttributesToArray(Array)
#5 /home/abc/abc/vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/Eloquent/Model.php(197): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->attributesToArray()
#6 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1176): Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model->attributesToArray()
#7 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1205): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->toArray()
#8 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->jsonSerialize()
#9 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php(71): json_encode(Array, 0)
#10 /home/abc/abc/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/JsonResponse.php(54): Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse->setData(Array)
#11 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php(31): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse->__construct(Array, 200, Array)
#12 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php(99): Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse->__construct(Array, 200, Array, 0)
#13 /home/abc/abc/app/Http/Controllers/API/candidate/CandidateController.php(118): Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory->json(Array)
#14 /home/abc/abc/app/Http/Controllers/API/candidate/CandidateController.php(66): App\Http\Controllers\API\candidate\CandidateController->respondWithToken('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...', Array)
#15 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): App\Http\Controllers\API\candidate\CandidateController->login(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('login', Array)
#17 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(239): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\API\candidate\CandidateController), 'login')
#18 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(196): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
#19 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(685): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
#20 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(59): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), 60, '1')
#25 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(687): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#27 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(662): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(628): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#29 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(617): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(63): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 /home/abc/abc/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#42 /home/abc/abc/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#44 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#45 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(140): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#46 /home/abc/abc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(109): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#47 /home/abc/public_html/index.php(55): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#48 {main}
```